# Can OpenSSL server know if SSL/TLS client ignore verifies 'sersver certificate'?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I write SSL/TLS server using OpenSSL API.
Some SSL/TLS client can ignore verify 'server certificate'. (e.g. `msmtp --tls-certcheck=off`)
SSL/TLS sever can know that SSL/TLS client ignore verify ?

I understand [SSL_get_verify_result](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_verify_result.html) can not know that.

> If no peer certificate was presented, the returned result code is X509_V_OK. This is because no verification error occurred, it does however not indicate success. SSL_get_verify_result() is only useful in connection with SSL_get_peer_certificate(3).

Doos OpenSSL have an API to know if the server certificate was ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the TLS handshake indicates if a client does not validate the server certificate at all or not properly. Therefore no OpenSSL API could be created to return such information.

The only way a server could detect such a wrong behavior is to provide an invalid certificate and see if the client wrongly accepts it, i.e. continues with TLS handshake and sends application data.